# Hi, I'm getting an error when performing a HTTP request with dart, it's a handshake exception. Can someone help me?

Tags: flutter, http, dart, request, response

**The Error is this one:**

HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:359))

**I tried some answers of stackoverflow, but no success.**

**The code is the following:**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


void main() async {

  var testConnection = await connectionTest();
  print(testConnection);
}

Future connectionTest() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://sophia.bc.ufg.br/mobile/busca.php?idioma=ptbr&acesso=web');
  try{
  var response = await http.get(url);
  return response.statusCode;
  } catch (e){
    return e;
  }
}
```

**I hope someone can help me out**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

please create a class like below:

```
import 'dart:io';

class HttpRequestOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}
```

and then in main function use it like this :

```
HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.
Now it's showing the message on the code syntax  for the override part of the class: 

'HttpRequestOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext)') isn't a valid override of 'HttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext?)').dart(invalid_override)

Do you know what might be it?

Comment: what is you'r flutter version ?

Comment: Flutter 2.2.3 and dart 2.13.4
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
http: ^0.13.3

Comment: did you add the permission for internet in manifest file ?
like this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the problem, because even trying only with dart isn't working on this website

Comment: @BrunoSoares change SecurityContext => SecurityContext?